# r : calculating time interval on condition

Tags: r

I would like to calculate `Day.Before_nextCLS` with 3 columns below

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Day, ~CLS,   ~BAL.D,
     0,    0,       NA,
     3,    0,    15000,
     6,    0,    10000,
    20,    0,     2000,
    25,    0, -4771299,
    26,    0, -1615637,
    27,    0,  -920917,
    31,    1,  -923089,
    32,    1,   -81863,
    33,    1,    19865,
    34,    1,     9865,
    37,    1,   609865
  )
```

Desired output is below tribble.
For `Day27`, `Day.Before_nextCLS` is 4,
because when `CLS` is 2, Day is 31, and interval between 27 and 31 is 4.

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Day, ~CLS,   ~BAL.D, ~Day.Before_nextCLS
     0,    0,       NA, 31,
     3,    0,    15000, 28,
     6,    0,    10000, 25,
    20,    0,     2000, 11,
    25,    0, -4771299, 6,
    26,    0, -1615637, 5,
    27,    0,  -920917, 4,
    31,    1,  -923089, NA, (for we don't have date when CLS ==2)
    32,    1,   -81863, NA,
    33,    1,    19865, NA,
    34,    1,     9865, NA,
    37,    1,   609865, NA,
  )
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a `lead` column and then do a group by subtract from the `last` value of lead column with the Day column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(DayLead = lead(Day)) %>% 
   group_by(CLS) %>% 
   mutate(Day.Before_nextCLS = last(DayLead) - Day, DayLead = NULL) %>% 
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
     Day   CLS    BAL.D Day.Before_nextCLS
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>              <dbl>
 1     0     0       NA                 31
 2     3     0    15000                 28
 3     6     0    10000                 25
 4    20     0     2000                 11
 5    25     0 -4771299                  6
 6    26     0 -1615637                  5
 7    27     0  -920917                  4
 8    31     1  -923089                 NA
 9    32     1   -81863                 NA
10    33     1    19865                 NA
11    34     1     9865                 NA
12    37     1   609865                 NA
```